# Confirm admob reward video was watched using a server

Tags: android, video, admob

I'm wanting to implement admob reward videos for my online android game.
Is there a way to confirm on my server that the admob video was watched and that someone hasn't just sent false "Video watched" flags to obtain rewards..

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As of November 27th, server-side rewarded video verification is in a closed beta.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/weXTAGZfYQ8/zITHZhGlCAAJ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Node.js piece of code

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');
const GOOGLE_AD_KEY_URL = 'https://gstatic.com/admob/reward/verifier-keys.json';

/**
 * Fetches the google public keys for the admob providers.
 * These keys changes time to time.
 */
 const getGoogleKeysMap = async () => {
 let googleKeyRes = await axios.get(GOOGLE_AD_KEY_URL);
 let {keys} = googleKeyRes.data;
 if (!keys) {
 throw new Error('No keys found from google keys');
 }
 /** For each of the keys array save it base 64 in decoded form in the key map */
 let keyMap = {};
 keys.forEach(k => {
 keyMap[`${k.keyId}`] = crypto.createPublicKey(k.pem);
 console.log(keyMap[`${k.keyId}`]);
 });
 return keyMap;
 };

 /**
 * Verifies the callback url query params string,
 * Resolves the promise if verification was successful, else fails.
 * Wanna 'debug' then pass the second parameter as true.
 * @param {String} queryUrl
  * @param {Boolean} debug 
 */
 async function verify(queryUrl, debug) {

 try {

 if (typeof queryUrl !== "string") throw new TypeError("URL needs to be string!");

  /**
  * Request coming as callback from admob must contain the 'signature' and the  'user_id'.
  * For more info https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv
  */
  const {signature, key_id} = queryString.parse(queryUrl);
   if (!signature) {
  throw new Error('No signature value exist in the URL param');
  }

 if(debug) {
 console.debug('Signature and KeyId ---');
console.debug(signature, key_id);
//  console.log('Signature and KeyId ---');
//  console.log(signature, key_id);
}

 let queryParamsString = queryUrl;
 if (queryParamsString.indexOf('?') > -1) {
 queryParamsString = queryUrl.split('?')[1];
 }

  if(debug) {
  console.debug('Query param string ---');
 // console.log('Query param string ---');
 console.debug(queryParamsString);
 // console.log(queryParamsString);
 }

 /**
 * As per admob, 
 * The last two query parameters of rewarded video SSV callbacks are always signature and key_id, in that order.
 * The remaining query parameters specify the content to be verified. 
 */
let contentToVerify = queryParamsString.substring(0,     queryParamsString.indexOf('signature') -1);

 if(debug) {
 console.debug('Content to verify ---');
 // console.log(contentToVerify);
 // console.log('Content to verify ---');
 console.debug(contentToVerify);
 }

let keyMap = await getGoogleKeysMap();

 if(keyMap[`${key_id}`]) {
 let publicKey = keyMap[`${key_id}`];
 const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
 verifier.update(contentToVerify);
  let result = verifier.verify(publicKey, signature, 'base64');
  if (result) {
   console.debug('Result ---');
   console.debug(result);
  return true;
 } else {
   console.debug('Failure ---');
   console.debug(result);
   throw new Error('Invalid Signature Supplied');
 }
 } else {
 console.debug('Key id provided doesn\'t exist ---');
 throw new Error('Key id provided doesn\'t exist in the google public keys');
}


  } catch (error) {

}

}

 module.exports.verify = verify;
```